# Execute function on a specific time (with params)

Tags: function

I was wondering how to execute a function in ANY language with specific params on a specific time, ofcourse i already thought about it myself.

I myself would create a function that checks every minute if a function should execute, therefor i would create an object which contains 2 keyvalues, datetime and the function with the literal params to execute, (such as sending a reminder to a specific user), but however, i dont think its the proper way, if anyone could explain/tell me a better way that would be awesome !.

Cheers,

Zayd Zarouali (Excuse me for my bad english.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to set cron job from a cpanel.

Create specific code as per your functionality and and then set it into your cpanel cron job. The cpanel cron job has all settings about which file to execute at what time of intervals.

Comment: What if you're not using cpanel at all would it be a good idea to create a own list or object with specific data to execute in the function? and if so would there be any security flaws ? (i cant figure out any security flaw only for password (which you could encrypt when you store those.))